# Remove Duplicate values (Project Name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using this code for displaying the content -

```
- @tasks.each do |task|
      %ul
        %li= task.project.name
        %ul
          %li= task.name
```

which gives a result something like this -

- Project1

  - Task1
- Project1

  - Task2

But I want the result representation to be like -

- Project1

  - Task1
  - Task2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group by

```
- @tasks.group_by(&:project_id).each do |project_id, tasks|
  %ul
    %li= tasks.first.project.name # or Project.find(project_id).name
    - tasks.each do |task|
      %ul
        %li= task.name
```

Comment: it's showing me this error - undefined method `group_by' for nil:NilClass

Comment: that means `@tasks` is `nil`